# HTTP OPTIONS in Xamarin Forms

Tags: rest, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Getting "204 Status Code" as No Content

[image: Option]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example of OPTIONS request:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Options, new Uri("http://myapi.com"));
var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
```

Just wondering why should you need to make one? OPTIONS is used to identify allowed request methods:

> To find out which request methods a server supports, one can use curl
>   and issue an OPTIONS request:
>
> `curl -X OPTIONS http://example.org -i`
>
> The response then contains an Allow header with the allowed methods:
>
> ```
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> Allow: OPTIONS, GET, HEAD, POST
> Cache-Control: max-age=604800
> Date: Thu, 13 Oct 2016 11:45:00 GMT
> Expires: Thu, 20 Oct 2016 11:45:00 GMT
> Server: EOS (lax004/2813)
> x-ec-custom-error: 1
> Content-Length: 0
> ```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS

Comment: In response throwing "Status code 204" "no content"  @EvZ

Comment: Did you add any content to your request? Please update your answer and share your code.

Comment: It is very weird that you use OPTIONS to send and email (check the definition). It should be POST or PUT, try to debug with postman.